# how to show multiple checkbox data of different group on a new form VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form in which there are two groupboxes and each groupbox contain 9 checkboxes. All I want to do is if user checked on different checkboxes and press the button the data of those check boxes can be seen on a new form in anything you suggest like label or textbox. I tried it with if else but it will be long code because he can select all checkboxes n both groups. please help me with code or suggestion. The image is here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ2e0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop over each checkbox in a group box .

```
For Each ctl In Me.GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If ctl.Checked Then
            'Access whatever data you need to populate your new form
            'I'd recommend using the .Tag property to store custom info
        End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

This gets the tag of the checkboxes and outputs them to the selected control:

```
Public Sub getcheck(ByVal ctrl As Control)
    ctrl.Text = ""
    For Each ctl In Me.GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If ctl.Checked Then
            ctrl.Text &= ctl.Tag & ", "
        End If
    Next
    For Each ctl In Me.GroupBox2.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If ctl.Checked Then
            ctrl.Text &= ctl.Tag & ", "
        End If
    Next
    ctrl.Text = ctrl.Text.Substring(0, ctrl.Text.Length - 2)
End Sub
```

Usage: `getcheck(Control)`

Example: `getcheck(Label1)` takes the tags of the selected checkboxes and writes them to `Label1`

Just set the tab of the checkboxes with:

```
    CheckBox1.Tag = "Red"
    CheckBox2.Tag = "Olive Green"
    CheckBox3.Tag = "Gray"
```

Etc.

Or just get the text of the checked checkboxes with this:

```
Public Sub getcheck(ByVal ctrl As Control)
    ctrl.Text = ""
    For Each ctl In Me.GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If ctl.Checked Then
            ctrl.Text &= ctl.Text & ", "
        End If
    Next
    For Each ctl In Me.GroupBox2.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If ctl.Checked Then
            ctrl.Text &= ctl.Text & ", "
        End If
    Next
    ctrl.Text = ctrl.Text.Substring(0, ctrl.Text.Length - 2)
End Sub
```